# How to add a "memo" to an action?

Tags: smart-contract, transactions, action

In an action in my contract, I want to attach some text to it, so that users can see the text in their transaction history using a block explore like eosflare.io.

I see that eosio.token has a "memo" parameter that does exactly what I want, however when I read the source code, it doesn't seem to use the "memo" at all. How does a block explore know it is a memo? How can I also add a "memo" to my action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block explore uses get actions functionality that lists all the transactions performed in that account. 
For e.g. when a transfer action is performed between two accounts as shown below

```
# cleos push action eosiotoken transfer '[user111,user222,"10.0000 SYS",
  "testing transfer"]' -p user111
```

The get actions of the user111 is as shown below

```
# cleos get actions user111
#  seq  when                              contract::action => receiver      trx id...   args
#    0   2018-07-03T10:37:28.000      eosiotoken::transfer => user111       14112283... {"from":"eosio","to":"user111","quantity":"100.0000 SYS","me...
#    1   2018-07-03T10:39:39.500      eosiotoken::transfer => eosiotoken    a24f51c5... {"from":"user111","to":"user222","quantity":"10.0000 SYS","m...
#    2   2018-07-03T10:39:39.500      eosiotoken::transfer => user111       a24f51c5... {"from":"user111","to":"user222","quantity":"10.0000 SYS","m...
#    3   2018-07-03T10:39:39.500      eosiotoken::transfer => user222       a24f51c5... {"from":"user111","to":"user222","quantity":"10.0000 SYS","m...
```

The get actions of user222 is as shown below

```
# cleos get actions user222
#  seq  when                              contract::action => receiver      trx id...   args
#    0   2018-07-03T10:39:39.500      eosiotoken::transfer => user222       a24f51c5... {"from":"user111","to":"user222","quantity":"10.0000 SYS","m...
```

As from the above results we get the list of all actions received by that account along with its **arguments**. The eosflare retrieves memo from the transfer action arguments.